# How to get floats to display properly? Sidebars divs to stay left, and content to remain float right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm unable to get the content to float right. I have two side bars that I want to display inline with each other, and the content to float to the right of it. Like this:

[Click here to see what I am trying to accomplish](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxj4R.png)

[Click here to see what is displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcAFq.png)

```css
.showMain {
  width: 550px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  font: normal 300 18px/24px 'aktiv-grotesk-std', sans-serif; }
  .showMain a{
    text-decoration: none;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.75s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.75s ease;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.75s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.75s ease;
    color: #d7df23; }
    .showMain a:hover {
    opacity: 0.6; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); }

.showSidebar {
  width: 304px;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: top;  }

.showSidebar2 {
  width: 304px;
  display: block;  }
```

```html
  <div class="rivnoShowInfo group row">
   <div class="showSidebar">
    <div class="showLocation">
     <h5 class="showVenue">
      Lincoln Park Athletic Club     </h5>
     <div class="showAddress">
      1019 W. Diversey Pkwy<br />
      Chicago, IL     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showDateCost">
     <h5 class="showDate">
      Session 1: July 25<br />
      Session 2: July 26<br />
      Session 3: August 1<br />
      Session 4: August 2<br />
      <br /><br />
      Event Time: 7:30AM – 8:45AM<br />
           </h5>
     <div class="showCost">
       Complete 4 Session Registration: $X<br />
      <br />
      Participant waivers can be downloaded from the links below and are required to be submitted in advance to: xxx@rivernorthchicago.com     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rivnoPageTitle eventSidebar register">
    </div>
   </div>


   <div class="showSidebar2">
    <div class="showLocation2">
     <h5 class="showVenue2">
      The Chopping Block     </h5>
     <div class="showAddress2">
      222 Merchandise Mart<br />
      Chicago, IL     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="showDateCost2">
     <h5 class="showDate2">
           </h5>
     <div class="showCost2">
       Complete 4 Session Registration: $X<br />
      <br />
      Participant waivers can be downloaded from the links below and are required to be submitted in advance to: xxx@rivernorthchicago.com     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rivnoPageTitle eventSidebar2 register">
    </div>




   <div class="showMain" style="display: block;">
    <span class="leadIn">Achieving Optimum Dance Performance – A New Workshop</span>
    <div class="page" title="Page 1">
<div class="section">
<div class="layoutArea">
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<div class="column">
<p>For nearly 20 years, <strong>River North Dance Chicago</strong> has delivered leading edge dance training programs focused primarily on improving dance skills and technique. Thousands of dancers have participated in these programs and applauded the inclusion of lunch seminars and mini-sessions on the topics of nutrition, injury prevention and conditioning. However, the overwhelming feedback has been these topics are great but only touch the surface of what a dancer needs to perform at an elite level.</p>
<p>RNDC is responding to that feedback with a new multi-module workshop entitled <strong>Achieving Optimum Dance Performance</strong>. This new offering is the result of collaborations with several leaders in the fields of sports medicine, injury prevention and body conditioning. These partners which include <strong>Midwest Orthopaedics at RUSH</strong>,<strong> Chicago Athletic Clubs</strong>, <strong>Jackie Caul at Presence Health</strong>, <strong>Athletico</strong>, and <strong>The Chopping Block</strong> have worked with RNDC to launch these new modules this summer.</p>
<p>This new workshop was designed as a comprehensive solution to meet the needs of elite dancers, but participants can register for each module separately. Lunch seminars and mini-sessions within RNDC current programs will continue. But for RNDC summer training participants looking to supplement those topics, or for dancers not participating in RNDC’s summer intensives, this new workshop is for you. River North Dance Chicago is committed to understanding and meeting the needs of aspiring and professional dancers, and is excited to bring this new product to the dance community.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Could you make a [mcve]...this looks like a width issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main content is in the `div class="showSidebar2">..</div>`. You should place it outside of this div, in the `div class="rivnoShowInfo group row">..</div>`.

There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but in my opinion the simplest way to solve this, is by placing a wrapper around your two sidebars, set the width to say 30%, then make your content 70% width. Set both your content and sidebar `display:inline-block`

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't think of that goal as having "two sidebars". It looks like one sidebar, with two articles of content. If you're willing to put one more container in your HTML, that should work well.

Usually, it makes sense to have the side content be the one that's "floated", while the "main content" uses all remaining space (and does NOT get floated). So I'd suggest trying the opposite of what you have now.

```css
body {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 10px;
}

sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: 2em;
}

main {
  font-size: 160%;
}
```

```html
<sidebar><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</sidebar>
<main>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</main>
```